# Why is my Firebird INSERT procedure failing?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I'm playing around with Web programming and trying to learn the principles involved.  I've got a Firebird database, and I'm trying to set up a simple "new user" procedure. It appears to run without error, but it doesn't actually create a new user record.

Here's my procedure:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

RECREATE PROCEDURE NEW_USER (
 NAME       VARCHAR(32),
 "PASSWORD" VARCHAR(128))
RETURNS (
 ID         INTEGER)
AS 
BEGIN
  if (exists(
    select * from USERS
    where NAME like :name)) then
    id = -1;
   else
     insert into USERS
     (NAME, PASSWORD, SALT)
     values (:name, :password, 's@lt')
     returning ID into :id;
   suspend;
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

(Please, no comments about password security.  I know.  This is only for research purposes right now.)

`USERS` contains 4 columns: ID (autoincrement int field powered by a generator), NAME, PASSWORD and SALT.

When I try to run it, like so:

```
select ID from NEW_USER('Test', 'password')
```

it executes, and returns an empty set.  If I then query the table:

```
select * from USERS
```

I get another empty set.

Any idea why the procedure isn't creating a new user?

Comment: What do you mean with "autoincrement int field powered by a generator"? The latest stable release, 2.5 doesn't support autoincrement fields, you have to manually create an trigger to fill in the `ID` field using the generator... if you haven't done that then this might be the reason nothing is inserted (failing to generate PK field). Oh and BTW I assume you do `commit` the query, right?

Comment: @ain: Aha! That's the problem.  I set this up with Firebird Maestro, and forgot to create the trigger to actually use the generator.  If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean with "autoincrement int field powered by a generator"? The latest stable release, 2.5 doesn't support autoincrement fields, you have to manually create an trigger to fill in the `ID` field using the generator... if you haven't done that then this might be the reason nothing is inserted (failing to generate PK field).